# Yii2 не видит css классы в ActiveForm->field()

Tags: php, css, yii2

Подскажите,пожалуйста, почему в

```
 ActiveForm->field()
```

может не видеть классы? а именно тут -

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'seminar_cost', ['class' => 'cost'])->textInput(['maxlength' => true]); ?>
```

не видит css класс - cost. в asset css файл подключен, в коде страницы его видно. Где-то еще надо указать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-widgets-activefield#$options-detail

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'seminar_cost', [
    'options' => [
        'class' => 'cost',
    ],
])->textInput(['maxlength' => true]); ?>
```